# Does Components.utils.unload() also unload subsidiary imports?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

Considering the following example:

```
Components.utils.import('chrome://something/content/main.jsm');

// inside main.jsm
Components.utils.import('chrome://something/content/sub.jsm');
```

Does unloading `main.jsm` also unload `sub.jsm` or should `sub.jsm` be unloaded in addition to `main.jsm`?

Note: The unloading is part of `shutdown()` in Firefox bootstrapped addon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not.

All modules are standalone and shared from the perspective of the loader. Which makes sense since all modules are loaded exactly once in the application. Well, until you `Cu.unload`, of course; though a subsequent `Cu.import` for that module would then load it again like the initial load.

So, a module is shared between all code accessing it. This means that the following will happen:

`other.jsm`

```
EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ['shared'];
shared = {abc:123};
```

`bootstap.js`

```
// Initial load of shared.jsm
Cu.import(".../other.jsm");
// Will be seen by all other modules, since this is shared. 
shared.def = 345;

// Will not propagate, as the top-level name shared is just a reference
// in the current scope, initially holding a reference to the object from shared,
// but now overriden.
shared = "string";

Cu.import(".../main.jsm");
```

`main.jsm`

```
// Since the module was already loaded before, the loader will not load it again
// but instead just use provide the references. 
Cu.import(".../other.jsm");

Cu.reportError(shared.abc); // 123
Cu.reportError(shared.def); // 456
```

This can come quite handy, e.g. when you need a central location to track/share/cache stuff, but also is a bit dangerous in regards to memory leaks on shutdown.

If you e.g. added another service getter to [`Services.jsm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm), e.g.:

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");

XPCOMUtils.defineLazyServiceGetter(Services, "uuid",
                                   "@mozilla.org/uuid-generator;1", "nsIUUIDGenerator");
```

Now that is problematic for two reasons:

1. `Services` will (initially) keep references to those string arguments around. And those string strings are owned by your module. `Cu.unload`ing your module will not fully destroy you module instance, since `Services` still references those strings, therefore your module cannot be fully garbage collected and your module instance would effectively become a [Zombie Compartment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Zombie_compartments).
2. Since all other add-ons and also the browser code get the same Services. there might be name clashes when adding new stuff to it. Something else might have added a `uuid` property already.

Also, **you should never `Cu.unload` modules that are not yours!**

> The unloading is part of shutdown() in Firefox bootstrapped addon.

Doesn't matter for the operation of `Cu.unload`. It will work the same, always.